# can anyone tell me why am i getting this error

Tags: android

```
public static Long relativeTime(String dateToParse) {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date d = null;
    try {
        d = sdf.parse(dateToParse);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy  HH:mm");

        output.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());


    String formattedTime = output.format(d);
    Date gg = null;
    try {
        gg = output.parse(formattedTime);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return gg != null ? gg.getTime() : 0;
}
```

it is giving me error

> java.lang.nullpointerexception attempt to invoke virtual 
>   method long java.util.date.gettime on a null object reference at
>   java.util.calendar.settimecalendar.java1197
>   java.text.simpledateformat.formatimplsimpledateformat.java527
>   java.text.simpledateformat.formatsimpledateformat.java829
>   java.text.dateformat.formatdateformat.java314
>   co.helpdesk.faveo.pro.helper.relativetimehelper.java202
>   co.helpdesk.faveo.pro.frontend.adapters.ticketoverviewadapter.onbindviewholderticketoverviewadapter.java64
>   co.helpdesk.faveo.pro.frontend.adapters.ticketoverviewadapter.onbindviewholderticketoverviewadapter.java27
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6356)

Comment: share all class file

Comment: which all class file is required?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.....it is solved actually the data is coming from the server.....luckily it was server fault....but again thanks....

Answer (score 1):

just change this one line in your code:

Instead of

```
Date d = null;
```

use

```
Date d = new Date();
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.....it is solved actually the data is coming from the server.....luckily it was server fault....but again thanks....

Answer (score 0):

After the `catch` statement write this code, and use `calender.getTime()` to get the time.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(gg);
```

And

```
return gg != null ? calendar.getTime() : 0;
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: but where i need to add this...

Comment: @sayarsamanta check the updated answer

Comment: dont think it is there...OP already is using a null check..`gg != null ? gg.getTime() : 0`

Comment: Edited the answer , please check.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.....it is solved actually the data is coming from the server.....luckily it was server fault....but again thanks....